# Acyclic Model Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, soft-question

I am looking for some applications of the Acyclic Model Theorem. I have only noticed its application to Alexander-Whiteny chain morphism $S_*(X\times Y)\to S_*(X)\otimes S_*(Y)$. Can anyone suggest more applications of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Künneth theorem ?

Comment: Homotopy invariance of homology. The fact that barycentric subdivision is chain homotopic to the identity map on singular chains.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I was told that homotopy invariance uses the method of acyclic models, but I didn’t see this yet. Do you know of any source which explicitly goes this route instead of using the decomposition of the cylinder? Moreover is it possible to prove excision in this way?

Comment: @PrudiiArca A standard way to prove excision is to use the fact I cited about barycentric subdivision. To prove homotopy invariance, use acrylic models to compare the singular chain complex functor $X \mapsto S(X)$ to the functor $X \mapsto S(X \times I)$. Munkres uses an approach like this in his algebraic topology book, I believe.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thank you very much. I can see that acyclic models might be the real reason behind the proofs of homotopy invariance and excission, but I have never seen this being stated explicitly. I will look up, what munkres does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The Künneth theorem
- Homotopy invariance of homology
- The fact that barycentric subdivision is chain homotopic to the identity map on singular chains

Comment: Hi there. Beyond Munkres, do you have other references or brief explanations for how the htpy invariance of homology and barycentric subdivision theorems are proven using this models theorem? I don't have my books to hand, and just looking at the theorem as stated in the original question it's not clear how "comparing $X\mapsto S(X)$ with $X\mapsto S(X\times I)$" gives you anything, neither in general having acyclic image

Comment: One reference is https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/the-method-of-acyclic-models/ and https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/some-applications-of-acyclic-models-in-algebraic-topology/, at least for homotopy invariance.  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/Barr-AcyclicModels2002.pdf Is another. Does Spanier cover it?